# как найти максимальное значение в словаре python со строками и числами? Не удается убрать сроку, чтобы проверить только числа в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь:

```
d = {
 'a': 3,
 'b': 'hello',
 'c': 4,
 'd': -3
}
```

Найти самое большое число из значений словаря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если не-числа нужно просто отбросить, и интересуют только значения словаря, без ключей, то как-то так что ли:

```
d = {
 'a': 3,
 'b': 'hello',
 'c': 4,
 'd': -3
}

print(max(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), d.values())))

# 4
```

`filter` фильтрует коллекцию по условию
`lambda x: isinstance(x, int)` - условие, что элемент коллекции имеет тип `int`

Comment: Только начинаю изучать, поэтому не получалось выкинуть строку. Ваш способ действительно помог, спасибо.
Но если есть время, могли бы обьяснить?

Comment: @NadyaMihaylenko Немного пояснил

Comment: спасибо огромное!